# Compilar programa Visual Studio com banco de dados e passar para outro PC

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Só uma pergunta básica, ao fazer um form com banco de dados no visual studio e depois de compilado é necessário o computador onde passarei os arquivos para execução ter o sql instalado ou consigo rodar o programa de boa sem nenhum erro?
Pergunto pois ao fazer um teste em outro PC passando os arquivos de compilação para rodar em outro PC aparece um erro de rede a instancia ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. Porém ao continuar o programa roda e grava no banco de dados de boa pois nos arquivos de compilação tem 2 arquivos do banco um com extensão mdf e ldf, não sei se futuramente possa acontecer algo ou como posso fazer para executar e ignorar este erro para que não aparece mais?

Comment: Sugiro você começar aprender o básico. Isto não está correto, mas te explicar tudo é praticamente um curso. Não faço a menor ideia do que você fez já que não mostrou, mas se deu erro não confie. É como comer um iogurte cheio de uma gosma verde em cima e dizer que não te matou.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, o banco de dados não compila junto com o seu programa.
Caso você queira usar o software localmente você terá que instalar o sql client na máquina do cliente, segue um link que irá te ajudar: http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2015/10/15/instalando-o-sql-server-junto-com-a-aplicacao/

Comment: Entendi, no caso eu não tenho acesso para instalar softwares, eu só passo os arquivos compilados para uma pasta de outro PC a unica pasta q tenho acesso, vou ler o arquivo e procurar outra forma, dei uma pesquisada e encontrei o sqlite tem o compact q não sei se são os mesmo, mas valeu!